# How can I accomplish, that the surface of the Ocean modifier isn't shown on the inside of a drifting transparent bottle?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, modifiers, objects, ocean-simulation

I'm trying to make an animation that shows multiple transparent bottles(which I used the solidify modifier on), that are swimming in the Sea(a normal ocean modifier surface).

On the inside of the bottles are messages that should be visible, but I can't find a way to delete the oceans surface on the inside of the bottle. Therefore it looks like the bottles have water in them.

I tried to use the Boolean modifier which didn't work.
Also I want to make an animation and not a single image.

[image: Two bottles in which the sea covers parts of the messages.]

(the water is supposed to be brown, as I'm doing this as an art-project)
Does anyone have an idea how I can delete/hide the water inside of the bottles, so that the messages are completely visible throughout the animation?

And if there is no possible way to do it this way, how can I make such a scene?

---

## Edit

@Jachim Michal Hi. Yes I've tried that, but there are two problems:

1. Because the Bottle is hollow, the Boolean Modifier only cuts away the space, that the bottle takes up and nothing from the inside.
   2.When I deleted the Solidify Modifier of the bottle, it worked, but the "hole" in the water disappears with the next frame.

Right now I have solved my problem by using the bottle as a brush and setting the canvas type to displacement:

But as you can see these ugly sharp edges appear. Does anyone know how I can make them smoother? Maybe by setting the Resolution of the Ocean Modifier to a higher number?

[image: Bottle]

Comment: Hello :). Boolean modifier comes to mind but I've no idea if it will look good :).